# Google Form Data Validation - Attendance Records using Google Forms and Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-data

I'm homeschooling 5 children this year (how am I that old?!). I have tried to streamline the process of attendance for a l.o.n.g. time.

I thought, `"I'll use a Google Form that they will simply select their name and the date.` (They can't cheat me on attendance because it should match the timestamp. Shhh.)
 `Here is the form:` [Google Form for Attendance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x525O.jpg) & [Google Form for Attendance drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C86sC.jpg)

`The information from the form presents in my Google sheet as:` [Google Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVlX1.jpg)

`I have several students that have attendance sheets:` [Several Student Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktDd9.jpg)

`My student record looks like this:` [Student Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiB1E.jpg)

**What I need help with**:
I need a P to be placed in the [Student Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiB1E.jpg) in the correct date as it is validated according to the information in the [Google Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVlX1.jpg).

`I need this to repeat for all of my student records. To search the data from` [Google Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVlX1.jpg) `and put the P in the correct places.`

I think I may be making it more difficult than it needs to be, or I need to set up my sheets a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Form Submit Installable trigger in Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers), so that whenever a form was submitted, the script function will be triggered to update the student record and place "P" on the date submitted.

Sample Code (Inbound script in your Google Sheets):

```
function UpdateStudentRecord(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formValues = e.values;
 
  var name = formValues[1];
  var date = new Date(formValues[2]);

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);

  //Get Month Year String and the  day
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var dateStr = Utilities.formatDate(date,timeZone, "MMMMM yyyy");
  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  
  //Find the row index of the submitted date 
  var colAValues = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getDisplayValues().flat();
  var rowIndex = colAValues.indexOf(dateStr);

  //Find the column index of the submitted day
  var row3Values = sheet.getRange("A3:3").getDisplayValues().flat();
  var colIndex = row3Values.indexOf(day);

  //Write P in the cell
  //Note that array index is in zero-based while sheet index is in one-based
  sheet.getRange(rowIndex+1, colIndex+1).setValue("P");
}
```

### Pre-requisite (Create a form submit trigger):

[image]

[image]

### What it does?

1. Every time a form was submitted, `UpdateStudentRecord()` will be executed
2. Get the submitted form values in the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) `e.values`
3. Get the name of the student and the submitted date
4. Get the submitted date string in "Month Year" format using [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format). And get the day using [getDate()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)
5. Get all columnA values, use `Array.flat()` to change 2-d array to 1-d array. Search for the date string obtained in step 4 using [Array.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)
6. Get all Row3 values, use `Array.flat()` to change 2-d array to 1-d array. Search for the day obtained in step 4 using [Array.indexOf()]
7. Write "P" on the row and column index obtained in step 5 & 6 using [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

### Note:

In this sample code, the sheet name should match the student name in form's drop-down list.

### Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered an issue so I could update the answer accordingly. You can provide the [sample sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383) when necessary